# HTTPS causes Joomla to revert back to old Domain when creating links

Tags: https, joomla, hyperlink

I have moved the website BradPPresents.com to BradP.com. **URLS ARE NOT SAFE FOR WORK**

The website links properly on HTTP but as soon as it uses HTTPS the links revert back to BradPPresents.com.

I assumed this was a Joomla! configuration.php file but it has already been changed to BradP.com.

Also, all instances that I can find of BradPPresents.com have been changed to BradP.com in the MySQL database.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Much appreciated,
Nick

Comment: Next time, note that your site is NSFW!  You may have gotten me fired!

Comment: Viewing from home, it looks like I overreacted a bit earlier.  Sorry.  That said, I do work at a place where they monitor traffic and have fired people for looking at adult sites.  This is not quite that, but the pix that came up were enough to make me fear losing my job, and I can't afford that.

Answer (score 1):

To others:  Before your curiosity gets the best of you and you decide to check this guy's site, please be aware that may be not suitable for work at some places.  Update:  I don't have privilege to edit the URLs statement that was added to the question, so I'll just update here:  The site is not an adult site in the classic sense, but one of those on how to get girls.  Still, some of the pix on the front page are a bit racy, so if you're at work, I still recommend staying away.

Check your server software's configuration.  It may be pointing port 443 (https) to a different default directory than port 80 (http).  If so, you'll need to change the default directory for port 443 to match that of port 80.

If you're using Apache, I expect there are files named httpd.conf and ssl.conf somewhere, possibly in separate directories.  (Most likely these directories will be at the same level or one will be a sub-directory of the other.  Possible starting points are /etc/httpd/ and /usr/local/apache2/.  These directories are usually named conf and conf.d.)  Both files probably have entries for DocumentRoot (although the one in ssl.conf may be commented out with a "#").  If neither is commented out and they don't match, change the one in ssl.conf.  See the [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) web site for more detail.

I've only used Apache, so I can't help with other servers.

And you probably know this, but I should mention it for completeness:  Don't forget to make back up copies of your existing configuration files before you edit them!  That way, if your changes don't work, you can go back to what you have.

Edit:  I missed that this was Joomla, which I've never used.  So, I'm not sure if this will be useful or not.